# Scala Help write Map

Tags: scala, dictionary

Need to implement this code
Help me to understand, please

```
object Task {
  type Map[K, V] = K => Option[V]

  def emptyMap[K, V]: Map[K, V] = ???

  def put[K, V](m: Map[K, V], key: K, value: V): Map[K, V] = ???

  def delete[K, V](m: Map[K, V], k: K): Map[K, V] = ???
}
```

Don't use standard library

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? Surely the first one shouldn't be _too_ hard to figure out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you're basically trying to model a `Map[K, V]` as a composition of functions.

As [jwvh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4993128/jwvh) said, the first one (`emptyMap`) should be pretty easy.
Think about it like this; given an empty map, if you try to retrieve a value from it what will you get?

```scala
val map = emptyMap[Int, String]
```

Having `map` declared in this way when we try to retrieve a value from it using a key we shouldn't get anything, since there is nothing there in the first place

```scala
map(1) == None
map(2) == None
```

So it seems that `emptyMap` could be implemented something like this

```scala
def emptyMap[K, V]: Map[K, V] = _ => None
```

Basically, an empty map returns `None` every time you try to find a value in it using a key.

Now let's look at `put`. Now we have to figure a way to add to the existing map the new *key* and *value*. Since we are working with functions because of the way `Map` is declared, **adding** a value to the map could prove to be quite a difficult task. But fret not, we will come up with a solution.

Looking at how we implemented `emptyMap` we can figure out that `put` should also be a function which takes a parameter of type `K` and returns a value of type `Option[V]`

```scala
def put[K, V](m: Map[K, V], key: K, value: V): Map[K, V] = parameter => ???
```

How do we go about returning the `Option[V]`?
Well, what happens when the parameter is equal to the `key` we just put in? (We just return the value)

```scala
def put[K, V](m: Map[K, V], key: K, value: V): Map[K, V] = 
    parameter => if(parameter == key) Some(value) else ???
```

If the `parameter` isn't equal to the `key` (that we just added to the map using `put`) it means that it might be equal to some other key in our map. And since our map is just a function which is waiting for a parameter we can implement it like this

```scala
def put[K, V](m: Map[K, V], key: K, value: V): Map[K, V] = 
    parameter => if(parameter == key) Some(value) else m(parameter)
```

So far so good. The last one is `delete`. This shouldn't be that difficult to implement now that we have `emptyMap` and `put`.

Before implementing `delete`, to get a  better understanding of our map, let's see how we can use it

```scala
val map = put(emptyMap[Int, String], 1, "A")
val anotherMap = put(map, 2, "B")

anotherMap(1) == Some("A")
anotherMap(2) == Some("B")
map(2) == None
```

When creating a map, we are just composing functions which await a parameter (which will be used to return the value). Only when we call them (e.g. `map(2)`) will they be executed.

Having this in mind let's implement `delete`. Delete should take a key and "delete" the value associated with it. In our case deleting a value just means that we should return `None` when the parameter we receive equals the key.

```scala
def delete[K, V](m: Map[K, V], key: K): Map[K, V] = 
    parameter => if(parameter == key) None else ???
```

But what about the rest of the map? Well we should leave it as is

```scala
def delete[K, V](m: Map[K, V], key: K): Map[K, V] = 
    parameter => if(parameter == key) None else m(parameter)
```

Soo... wrapping things up, we ended with something like this.

```scala
object Task {
  type Map[K, V] = K => Option[V]

  def emptyMap[K, V]: Map[K, V] = _ => None

  def put[K, V](m: Map[K, V], key: K, value: V): Map[K, V] = 
    parameter => if(parameter == key) Some(value) else m(parameter)

  def delete[K, V](m: Map[K, V], key: K): Map[K, V] = 
    parameter => if(parameter == key) None else m(parameter)
}
```